# Fatal error: Cannot use isset() - Tried to work around the error, where's the syntax error?

Tags: php

I get the error in the title. Normally I got this error so far: `Notice: Undefined index: page in`, so I tried this way to remove the notice:

```
if ( !isset($page = strtolower($_GET['page'])))
or $page = strtolower($_GET['page'])
);
```

Original code that triggers the notice: 
`$page = strtolower($_GET['page']);`

What is the syntax so that the notice is no longer triggered?

Comment: you can have only [one ore more (mixed) variable(s)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php#refsect1-function.isset-notes) inside isset, not an expression or something similar.

Comment: Put the `isset` in the assignment, not the other way around

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this. What are you trying to check for?

Comment: i think `if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])){$page=strtolower($_GET['page']);}`

Comment: `$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? strtolower($_GET['page']) : false;` (or null, or '',  or 0, whatever you need as default for $page in case $_GET['page'] is not set.)

Comment: You can also try `$page = strtolower($_GET['page']??'');` in PHP 7+ ([null coalesce](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op))

Comment: u also need to check double `isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])` u must need to check empty string also

Comment: `empty` also checks for `isset`, so the `isset` call is unnecessary when using `empty`

Comment: @Sha just for info: this ( ? : ) is called [tenary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), which is basicly a shorthand for if, then,else

Comment: @aynber: yes, u r right.